# Parcel debugging experience inconsistent

Tags: vscode-debugger, parceljs

I have a rather simple setup:
- parcel 1.12.4
- vs code 1.43.2
- chrome 80.0.3987.149 on macOS
- chrome debugger extension
- node v13.11.0
- a simple index.html that uses main.js which imports moment.js and a module of mine.

Snippet from launch.json

```
  {
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch Chrome",
    "url": "http://localhost:1234",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
  }
```

When I serve everything via  `parcel index.js` it compiles and runs fine.

- When I set a breakpoint in *main.js* , it is grayed out and ignored.
- When I resort to `debugger;`, this breakpoint works and I can also set other breakpoints via VS Code or Chrome.
- Most of the time, the breakpoint shows up in a tab *main.js **read only** inlined content ...* – the extract of the sourcemap/bundle which is a bit weird but understandable.
- Sometimes the breakpoint shows up in *dist/main.fb6bbcaf.js*, essentially forcing me to debug inside the generated bundle.

This is a bit inconsistent and I did not find any pattern what happens when. I plan to use parcel/javascript with a number of students and I anticipate that they will be confused.

What can I do to get a more consistent debugging experience?